# Conditional debit from credits and running balance using SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I've data like below in a table **cryptotransactionledger**

| id | transaction_typeid | transaction_type | amount | totalcoins |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | bitcoin-credit | 30 | 30 |
| 2 | 2 | ethereum-credit | 20 | 50 |

If I spend bitcoin, I'm putting a new entry like below in the same table with transaction_typeid 3 and similarly for ethereum with transaction_typeid 4

| id | transaction_typeid | transaction_type | amount | totalcoins |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | bitcoin-credit | 30 | 30 |
| 2 | 2 | etherium-credit | 20 | 50 |
| 3 | 3 | bitcoin-debit | -10 | 40 |
| 4 | 4 | etherium-debit | -5 | 35 |

Suppose if my final data in the table is like below, I will have 35 bitcoin and 20 ethereum remaning.

| id | transaction_typeid | transaction_type | amount | totalcoins |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | bitcoin-credit | 30 | 30 |
| 2 | 2 | etherium-credit | 20 | 50 |
| 3 | 3 | bitcoin-debit | -10 | 40 |
| 4 | 4 | etherium-debit | -5 | 35 |
| 5 | 1 | bitcoin-credit | 15 | 50 |
| 6 | 2 | etherium-credit | 10 | 60 |
| 7 | 4 | etherium-debit | -5 | 55 |

How can I arrive at below balance summary using SQL after reducing all debits from respective credits

| id | transaction_type | amount | totalcoins |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | bitcoin-credit | 35 | 35 |
| 2 | etherium-credit | 20 | 55 |

Comment: What's the calculation for bitcoin-credit 35 as total coins?

Comment: @RahulBiswas totalcoins is nothing but running total of amount field in each row. Since bitcoin-credit is first row it's showing same value of amount field which is 35. For second row, it did amount + previous totalcoins which is 20 + 35 = 55.

Comment: @Serg I've updated the table structure in question to include id column also.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks to all those gave suggestions and different solutions.
I've finally used below query that provides me the results as expected.

```
WITH cte1
 AS (SELECT a.*,
            CASE
              WHEN ( transaction_typeid = 1
                      OR transaction_typeid = 3 ) THEN 0
              ELSE 1
            END AS category
     FROM   cryptotransactionledger a
     ORDER  BY id),
 cte2
 AS (SELECT CASE
              WHEN ( category = 0 ) THEN 'bitcoin-credit'
              ELSE 'etherium-credit'
            END         AS transaction_type,
            Sum(amount) AS amount
     FROM   cte1 o
     GROUP  BY category),
 cte3
 AS (SELECT Row_number()
              OVER (ORDER BY c.transaction_type) AS id,
            c.*
     FROM   cte2 c) SELECT f.*,
     Sum(amount) OVER(ORDER BY f.id) AS total_coins FROM cte3 f;
```

[Link to DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=9e4017429d7bdaa81c949ba53f1c3d90)

Answer (score 0):

I would forget "transaction types" for the final result and just focus on the coin itself.  You data model is rather strange, because you don't have a separate column for the type of coin.  But you can extract it from the `transaction_type` column.

In addition, your comments suggest that `totalcoins` should be the last value in the column.  For "bitcoin" that would be 50, not 35.

In any case, you can use aggregation.  I would suggest:

```
select regexp_substr(transaction_type, '^[^-]+') as coin,
       sum(amount) as amount,
       max(totalcoins) keep (dense_rank first oder by id desc) as totalcoins
from cryptotransactionledger tl
group by regexp_substr(transaction_type, '^[^-]+');
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=07d4c903f0135a4b34861267917b83ff) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Hi Gordon, thanks for your answer but I cannot avoid the transaction_typeid. What I actually try to achieve is I want to deduct transaction_typeid 3 from transaction_typeid 1 and transaction_typeid 4 from transaction_typeid 2 which would give my final result. Once we get this in CTE, easily we can do the cumulative sum to calculate totalcoins field.

Comment: Hi Gordon, sorry if my comment on totalcoins was misguiding. Totalcoins in my last table is nothing but running total of amount column. That’s why it’s 35 for first row (Bitcoin-credit) and 35 + 20 = 55 for second row (Ethereum-Credit). Final Bitcoin-credit is nothing Bitcoin-Credit (1) minus Bitcoin-Debit (4) from my 3rd table in question and similarly for Ethereum(2-4).

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you have the tables `ledger` and `coin_types`:

```
create table ledger (id varchar2(3) primary key, 
                 coin_type varchar2(2), 
                 amount number(5)
                 );

create table coin_types (id varchar2(2) primary key, 
                         alias varchar2(100));
```

These DML-Statements are representing your "final data":

```
insert into coin_types values (1, 'bitcoin');
insert into coin_types values (2, 'etherium');

insert into ledger values (1, 1, 30);
insert into ledger values (2, 2, 20);
insert into ledger values (3, 1, -10);
insert into ledger values (4, 2, -5);
insert into ledger values (5, 1, 15);
insert into ledger values (6, 2, 10);
insert into ledger values (7, 2, -5);
```

Your first step should be to sum up the amounts, grouped by your coin type:

```
  select l.coin_type, 
         c.alias,
         sum(l.amount) amount_coin
    from ledger l, coin_types c
   where l.coin_type = c.id
group by l.coin_type, c.alias
```

You can then use this select to get your "totalcoins" as a cumulative sum, ordered by your coin_type ([see Oraclee Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions163.htm)):

```
   select coin_type, 
          alias, 
          amount_coin, 
          sum(amount_coin) over (order by coin_type) totalcoins 
      from(
          select l.coin_type, 
                 c.alias,
                 sum(l.amount) amount_coin
            from ledger l, coin_types c
           where l.coin_type = c.id
        group by l.coin_type, c.alias
           );
```

Here is a working SQL-Fiddle: [SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/90c7b)

Comment: Thanks for your answer but in my case I have 4 different types. 3 - Bitcoin Debit, 4 - Ethereum Debit. In your data model representing my final data you’ve used typeid 1 and 2 for debits also which is not my case, if you look at my final data in question it’s using 3 and 4 for debits. So what I’m looking for here is actually how to map 1-3 and 2-4 for finding the balance.

Answer (score -1):

I would create a table of tran types

```
create table tran_types (
   id int primary key,
   coin_Name varchar2(100),
   op_Name varchar2(100)
   );

insert into tran_types  
select 1, 'bitcoin', 'credit' from dual union all
select 2, 'etherium','credit' from dual union all
select 3, 'bitcoin', 'debit'  from dual union all
select 4, 'etherium','debit'  from dual;
```

This way you can group transactions to get totals and visualise total row headers as needed

```
select t.id transaction_typeid, t.coin_Name || '-' || t.op_Name transaction_type, 
    s.amount, s.total_coins
from (
  select t.coin_Name, sum(amount) amount
    , sum(sum(amount)) over(order by t.coin_Name) total_coins
  from ledger r
  join tran_types t on r.tran_type = t.id
  group by t.coin_Name
) s
join tran_types t on t.op_name = 'credit' and t.coin_Name = s.coin_Name
order by t.coin_Name;
```